# Converting a timestamp to relative time

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I want convert **`timestamp` to relative time** using `Java` in `Android` like **`Facebook`**. I'm using `android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` but not getting expected result.

My code :

```
public static CharSequence  getTimeAgo(long timestamp) {

    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);

}
```

Results :

```
5 sec ago
5 min ago
5 hr ago
5 days ago
```

Expected results :

```
1 sec
5 secs
1 min
5 mins
1 hr
5 hrs
5 days
Yesterday at 11:48 pm
27 Jan at 6:52 pm
25 Aug 2019 at 7:53 pm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return time same as `Facebook`:

```
public static String getTimeAgo(long time) {

    final DateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
    final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM 'at' h:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
    final DateFormat sdfY = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy 'at' h:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);

    final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
    final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
    final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
    final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;

    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        time *= 1000;
    }

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar timeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeCal.setTimeInMillis(time);

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    final long diff = now - time;
    if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "Just now";
    } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return "1 min";
    } else if (diff < 59 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
        return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " mins";
    } else if (diff < 2 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return "1 hr";
    } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hrs";
    } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
        return ("Yesterday at " + capsAMtoSmall(sdfTime.format(timeCal.getTime())));
    } else if (today.get(Calendar.YEAR) == timeCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        return capsAMtoSmall(sdf.format(timeCal.getTime()));
    } else {
        return capsAMtoSmall(sdfY.format(timeCal.getTime()));
    }
}
```

```
private static String capsAMtoSmall(String time) {
    return time.replace("AM", "am").replace("PM","pm");
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

You just need to pass timestamp here

```
   public static String dayStringFormat(long msecs) {
        final long ONE_SECOND = 1000L;
        final long ONE_MINUTE = 60000L;
        final long ONE_HOUR = 3600000L;
        final long ONE_DAY = 86400000L;
        final long ONE_MONTH = 2592000000L;
        final long ONE_YEAR = 31536000000L;
        int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long difference = currentTime - msecs;
        if (difference < ONE_MINUTE) {
            long timeAgo = difference / ONE_SECOND;
            int finalUnits = (int) timeAgo;
            return "Just Now"
        } else if (difference < ONE_HOUR) {
            long timeAgo = difference / ONE_MINUTE;
            int finalUnits = (int) timeAgo;
            return  finalUnits + " " + "Minutes Ago";
        } else if (difference < ONE_DAY) {
            long timeAgo = difference / ONE_HOUR;
            int finalUnits = (int) timeAgo;
            return finalUnits + " " + "Hours Ago";
        } else if (difference < ONE_MONTH) {
            long timeAgo = difference / ONE_DAY;
            int finalUnits = (int) timeAgo;
            return  finalUnits +" " + "Days Ago";
        } else if (difference < ONE_YEAR) {
            long timeAgo = difference / ONE_MONTH;
            int finalUnits = (int) timeAgo;
            return  finalUnits + " " + "Months Ago";
        } else {
            long timeAgo = difference / ONE_MONTH;
            int finalUnits = (int) timeAgo;
            return  finalUnits + "" + "Months Ago";

        }
    }
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: Not working, your code always shows 625 months ago.

Answer (score -1):

I converted "Kalpesh Rupani's" answer to Kotlin as an Extension to Long, and it's working perfectly.

```
fun Long.relativeDate(): String {
val ONE_SECOND = 1000L
val ONE_MINUTE = 60000L
val ONE_HOUR = 3600000L
val ONE_DAY = 86400000L
val ONE_WEEK = 604800000L
val ONE_MONTH = 2592000000L
val ONE_YEAR = 31536000000L
//int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val difference = currentTime - this
if (difference < ONE_MINUTE) {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_SECOND
    return if (timeAgo < 3 )
        "just now"
    else
        "$timeAgo seconds ago"
} else if (difference < ONE_HOUR) {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_MINUTE
    return if (timeAgo == 1L)
        "a minute ago"
    else
        "$timeAgo minutes ago"
} else if (difference < ONE_DAY) {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_HOUR
    return if (timeAgo == 1L )
        "an hour ago"
    else
        "$timeAgo hours ago"
} else if (difference < ONE_WEEK) {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_DAY
    return if (timeAgo == 1L )
        "yesterday"
    else
        "$timeAgo days ago"
} else if (difference < ONE_MONTH) {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_WEEK
    return if (timeAgo == 1L )
        "last week"
    else
        "$timeAgo weeks ago"
} else if (difference < ONE_YEAR) {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_MONTH
    return if (timeAgo == 1L )
        "last month"
    else
        "$timeAgo months ago"
} else {
    val timeAgo = difference / ONE_MONTH
    return "$timeAgo Months Ago"
}
```

}